# why does Files.probeContentType return null

Tags: java, macos

i am using java se7 on mac, the oracle preview.

My problem is that "Files.probeContentType" returns null...is it possible that its due to the early status of se7 for mac?
My code:

```
if(directory == null) return;
String content = null;
try {
    content = Files.probeContentType(directory.toPath());
} catch (IOException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(main, e.toString());
    return;
}
if(content == null)
{
    return;
}
else if(content.contains("image"))
{
    main.pctviewer.setImage(directory);
}
```

the name of the file is:

"/Users/admin/Desktop/temp/q12/formulare/Bildschirmfoto 2012-09-11 um 17.57.59.png"

and in debug mode in eclipse if i hover above File "file path = Unis-path(id:145)" is red

Comment: an [alternate approach can be found here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19712111/26510)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have reported the bug to oracle again, hoping they will backport the jdk8 solution (I don't have much hope but you never know).

In the meantime you can use my own backport of the FileTypeDetector available at https://github.com/jeantil/jdk7-mimeutils the maven project packages to a jar which can be added to your classpath to enable mime type detection.  I also provide a mime.types file to put in your home folder for the detection to work correctly. I extracted the mime.types file from some version of apache so it's pretty complete.

Comment: nope and my bug report never made it through :( my blog had a couple changes: the link is now http://blog.byjean.eu/java/2013/08/22/making-jdk7-nio-filetypedetection-work-on-mac-osx.html

Comment: 2015 - OS El Captain and still buggy!

Comment: 2018 - OS High Sierra, JDK 8, always null as well.

Comment: 2019 - MacOS High Sierra, JDK 8, returns `null`.

Comment: 2019 - MacOS Mojave JDK8 - returns null

Comment: 2022 - MacOS Big Sur, JDK 8 - returns null

Answer (score 4):

I found that the FileTypeDetector is buggy on OS X: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7133484

Apparently this will be fixed in Java 8.

Comment: It seems this is still an open bug as of July 2016. https://github.com/pawandubey/griffin/issues/38

Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below approach to get mime type of file in Java 8 :

```
String location = "/Users/user/Desktop/leaf.jpg";
File file = new File(location);
Path source = Paths.get(location);
MimetypesFileTypeMap m = new MimetypesFileTypeMap(source.toString());
System.out.println( m.getContentType(file) );
```

Output of the above code is :  'image/jpg'