# Alternative to Files.probeContentType?

Tags: java

In a web project, users upload their files, but when I receive them on the server, they are being stored as .tmp files rather than their original file extension (this is my preferred behavior as well).

However, this is causing a problem with `Files.probeContentType()`. While locally for me, on my Linux dev machine, `Files.probeContentType()` works correctly and does determine the right mime type, when I upload my project to the production server (amazon beanstalk), it doesn't seem to correctly determine the mime type.

From reading the javadocs, it seems that the implementation of `Files.probeContentType()` are different, and I think that on production server, it is reading the file extension and so, is unable to determine the content type.

What's a good, and quick alternative to `Files.probeContentType()` which will accept a `File` argument and return a string like `image/png` as the resulting mime type?

Comment: Can you store them as `filename.extension.tmp`?

Comment: @PM77-1 No, that's not what I want anyway. A user could just rename their .exe file to a .png and it would be accepted by the server. I'd rather it actually reads the file to determine the correct mime type.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Take a look at the [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/). It can easily determine a mime type:

```
 Tika tika = new Tika();
 File file = ...
 String mimeType = tika.detect(file);
```

Here's a minimal required maven dependency:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
    <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.12</version>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: Do you know which artifact for maven I need to add to my project from their maven page? http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tika . they have many ambigious ones like `tika-parsers` and just `tika`', I'm not sure which one I need for this purpose.

Comment: Sure, see updated answer. tika-core was completely enough for my project when I was facing the similar issue

Comment: Very helpful thanks ! Before adding the dependency, make sure to get the latest version by checking here : http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tika/tika-core

Comment: I needed to include tika-parsers to handle detecting mimetypes of jpgs and tiffs.

Comment: @EdgeCaseBerg This works for me with Tika 1.12, core only (no tika-parsers): `t.detect("file.jpeg")`, `t.detect("file.jpg")`, `t.detect("file.tiff")` (results in `image/jpeg  image/jpeg  image/tiff`).

Comment: This just works. It event returns `text/x-log` for an empty file ending with .log extension.

Answer (score 12):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/847849/416300) suggests using:

```
InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(is);
//...close stream
```

Answer (score -3):

This also works

`String mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(new File(path).getName());`

Comment: This will resolve type from file name instead of trying to read metadata inside the file, the opposite of what OP asked