# Java wrapper for Unix file cmd

Tags: java, linux

I am trying to access some statistics (file type description) of files by executing the 'file' command via java. Current implementation using `Runtime.exec()` and it's a bit overhead for my application

Is there any pure Java wrapper for Unix file command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [Files.probeContentType](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#probeContentType-java.nio.file.Path-)

- [Alternative approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19711956/alternative-to-files-probecontenttype)

Answer (score 0):

Since java is platform-independent, no it doesn't have any Unix or other OS-specific wrappers. `Runtime.exec()` is an acceptable way to do what you want, but better yet to use [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) class (See method `start()`). Alternatively, you could access directories and files using regular java classes. See class [File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html) or read about package [java.nio.file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 0):

[jproc](https://github.com/fleipold/jproc) is a library that makes calling external tools straight-forward. It handles
the consumption of `stdin` and `stdout` and also checks the exit code.

Calling the `file` utility becomes a one liner:

`String output = ProcBuilder.run("file", "somepath");`

The only thing that is left to do is parsing the output.

To get it onto your classpath you can use its maven coordinate:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.buildobjects</groupId>
    <artifactId>jproc</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```