# Identify File Type in Java

Tags: java, file

I want to check that the user uploads only a particular file format (say text files only).

I've written a verification mechanism which checks for format after the file name like this

```
filename.txt
```

But, this created a problem when it was accepting other files also (like excel files) which are saved as .txt like

```
myexcelfile.txt is being assumed as a text file even when it is an excel file
```

So, What would be the unique parameter to check for to make sure that the uploaded file is of the required type?

Using apache-commons uploader, servlets.

======================EDIT=====================

Based on answers below, I've tried

```
FileInputStream my = new FileInputStream(uploadedFile2);
InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(my);
String mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(inputStream);
```

But is always returning a null value.

[probe content type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/spi/FileTypeDetector.html) is based on filename extension and also there is a bug with [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12407479/why-does-files-probecontenttype-return-null.), checked that too.

I don't prefer to use third party file verifiers, I believe that this problem will have a logical solution.

Comment: Just check for extensions? `.xslx` and `.xls`?

Comment: Told you in my above question, you can save a text file as .xlsx though Microsoft excel identifies this as an excel file it won't be able to open it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) has [content detection](http://tika.apache.org/1.5/detection.html) capabilities for a wide range of [file formats](http://tika.apache.org/1.5/formats.html).  From the documentation, one of the simplest ways to detect content type is based on the following code:

```
// default tika configuration can detect a lot of different file types
TikaConfig tika = new TikaConfig();

// meta data collected about the source file
Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
metadata.set(Metadata.RESOURCE_NAME_KEY, f.toString());

// determine mime type from file contents   
String mimetype = tika.getDetector().detect
    (TikaInputStream.get(uploadedFile2), metadata);
System.out.println("File " + uploadedFile2 + " is " + mimetype);
```

If `mimetype` is `text/plain`, then the file or stream contains plain text content.

Comment: Apache Tika doesn't work for documents. DOCX , XLSX, XLS and DOC

Answer (score 2):

You could open the file and read the first few bytes into a `byte[]` and check the values to see if it matches the known magic numbers for a particular file format. I tried finding out what that would be for an Excel file (pre-XML; the xlsx file format would identify as a zip file), but I haven't really found much data about that. The closest thing I've found so far was looking at the code for a Java Excel file parser library.

The old Excel data format used what's called BIFF. Check out the [Apache POI library](http://poi.apache.org/) for parsers and such for those types of files. From the looks of it, the magic numbers for an Excel file would probably be `00 06 10 00` (for BIFF8 worksheet), or `00 05 10 00` (BIFF7 worksheet, sounds rather old).

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 Files.probeContentType(Paths.get("~/a.xls"))
```

note that output depends on system content type detector - it may be different on different machines.

As for me, this code returns

```
application/vnd.ms-excel
```

Comment: As said above, probeContentType is dependent on file name extension

Comment: Then I suppose you need to parse every file type individually. For example, .xls files contain ' Excel ' word (` grep -q ' Excell ' a.txt` returns 0 exit code)

Comment: The method "probeContentType" is a method of java.nio.file.spi.FileTypeDetector, not of java.nio.file.Files.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static String getMimeType(String fileUrl) {
    String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(fileUrl);
    return MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
}
```

Comment: MimeTypeMap appears to be a class available in Android.  It is not a part of Java SE.