# Getting the real mime type in a renamed file

Tags: android, file, mime-types

I have a problem finding out what is the real mime type of a file whose name and extension was changed.  For example, the file "app.exe" renamed to "picture.png" or "document.pdf", how can I get that the real mime type is ".exe"?

Thanks for your help.

Regards,

Comment: Check out the file signature ("magic" bytes at the very beginning of the file). Plain text files (note: csv files are plain text files) do not have it.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Very useful information about magic bytes. But, how can I verify that a plain text file is really a plain text file?

Comment: Well, if all the magic signatures you checked do not match, then it's ***probably*** a plain text file. As I said, csv data files and programming source files (including batch/scripts but excluding markup languages) are indistinguishable from actual texts.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22801282/6134394) answer. The main idea - all files have their type inside themselves. It means that you can read first bites and use this information to identify filetype and manually add extension or do whatever you want.

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for the information, I have advanced a lot in solving the problem using the magic bytes to identify the filetype.